# How to Override the Default Float Restrictions of Table and Figure

Tags: floats, positioning, rotating

In brief, the [h!] option to override the default float restrictions for tables and figures does not appear to work.

I am trying to insert a table that takes up a whole page.  Due to its size, I have had to define it as a `sidewaystable` as follows:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}[h!]
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{5cm}|}
      \hline
      Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4 \\
      \hline
      \hline
        .
        .
        .
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{A Caption}
  \end{center}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

No matter what I try to do, LaTeX always places it at the end of the document, after my bibliography (i.e. references).  What's worse is that any table that I define after this, no matter how big or small, is also placed at the end of the document (after the problematic table).

I seem to have a similar problem with figures.  While the `[h!]` option places some figures immediately after the paragraph I have referenced them in (as expected), LaTeX places other figures one or two pages following the referencing paragraph.

If it helps any, I am using the following document class:

```
\documentclass[JMC]{degruyter-journal}   % Journal of Mathematical Cryptology
```

I am also using the following packages:

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[lined,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
```

Comment: Do you receive any overfull box warnings? How about adding a `\clearpage` immediately after the the `figure` environment? Since the `figure` *will* be a full page, does using the float specifier `p` help? Also, since you're loading the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float), you could use the provided `H` specifier which is more strict than `!h`.

Comment: @Werner - No `overfull` warnings, however, I do receive `underfull` warnings for each `hbox` that is defined (badness 10000).  I also seem to get the following warning generated for the table, and each of the figures I have inserted into the document: `LaTeX Warning: '!h' specifier changed to '!ht'`.

Comment: @Werner - P.S. Adding a `\clearpage` immediately after the `figure` environment, or using the `p` specifier places the figure on a separate page.  Furthermore, using the `H` specifier for the problematic table causes it to disappear from the document altogether!!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the following set of instructions works well in the circumstances you describe; I use the `\afterpage` command provided by the `afterpage` package.

```
...
\afterpage{\clearpage
\begin{sidewaystable} % no need for the [h] or even [h!] specifier
\centering % better than \begin{center} ... \end{center}
\begin{tabular}...
...
\end{tabular}
\caption{xyz} \label{tab:xyz}
\end{sidewaystable}
\clearpage } % note the "}" to denote the end of the argument of \afterpage
...
```

The key is the use of `\clearpage` commands both before *and* after the sideways{figure/table} environment.

Comment: Thanks!  This not only has solved the problem with the large table.  It appears to have fixed the problem with other figures/tables in the document.  Once again, thank you!